# How to make dice shaker with accelerometer?

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I want to make an Android app that can roll the dice with shake the phone.
I already set up the accelerometer sensor in android studio.
The problem is, how to make the the app come with an random number in dice with shaking the phone until reach the limit that i set before.

This the MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.pc.accelerometer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

private TextView xText, yText, zText;
private Sensor mySensor;
private SensorManager SM;
int ab;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Create our Sensor Manager
    SM = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

    // Accelerometer Sensor
    mySensor = SM.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);

    // Register sensor Listener
    SM.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

    // Assign TextView
    xText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.xText);
    yText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.yText);
    zText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.zText);
//        yText.setText(ab);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SM.registerListener(this, mySensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    // Not in use
}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if(event.values[0]>3){
        final int[] proper_noun = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
        Random random = new Random();
        int index = random.nextInt(proper_noun.length);
        ab = proper_noun[index];

        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ShakeActivity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putInt("angka",ab);

        i.putExtras(b);

        startActivity(i);
        SM.unregisterListener(this);

    }
    xText.setText("X: " + event.values[0]);

//        yText.setText("Y: " + event.values[1]);
//        zText.setText("Z: " + event.values[2]);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

This is ShakeActivity.java

```
package com.example.pc.accelerometer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Created by PC-Parinussa on 6/26/2017.
 */

public class ShakeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView namaTv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.shake_layout);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
        int angka = b.getInt("angka");
    namaTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.shakeID);

    namaTv.setText("Random angka : "+angka);
}
}
```

Comment: This is how I would do it. Set up a threshold for the x,y,z values (let it be 10.0). When all of your directions are above the threshold for 0.5-1 seconds, chances are someone is shaking the phone. Not sure what would be the most accurate threshold I think you have to "trial and error" that. Keep rolling the dice until your values fall below the threshold again.